# Access to component property inside a component method called by an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, components

I have a component that toggles when the window is clicked anywhere.

To achieve that I bind a component method as global event to the `body` element.

Moreover, I need to access a component property inside the component method that is called by the click event bound to the `body` element.

But it doesn't work:

**app/components/example-component.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  exampleProperty: 'example value',

  didInsertElement() {
    console.log('start didInsertElement() ************************************************************');
    console.log('- "this" is the Ember.js component:');
    console.log(this.$());
    console.log('- "this.exampleProperty" has the Ember.js component value:');
    console.log(this.exampleProperty);
    Ember.$('body').click(this.exampleMethod).click();
    console.log('end didInsertElement() ************************************************************');
  },
  exampleMethod(event) {
    console.log('start exampleMethod() ************************************************************');
    console.log('- "this" is the DOM element that has triggered the event:');
    console.log(Ember.$(this));
    // console.log(this.$()); This doesn't work
    console.log('- "this.exampleProperty" is undefined:');
    console.log(this.exampleProperty);
    console.log('end exampleMethod() ************************************************************');
  },
});
```

How to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it provides the cleaner approach you are looking for, but `.bind(this)` might help.

```
// Using bind:
Ember.$('body').click(this, this.exampleMethod.bind(this)).click();

// Results in the below working as you desire:
this.$(); //returns jQuery.fn.init [div#ember256.ember-view, context: div#ember256.ember-view]

Ember.get(this, 'exampleProperty'); //returns 'example value'
```

Comment: Works great! Actually only the `.bind(this)` function is necessary, the `this` context is not necessary anymore. So then:
`Ember.$('body').click(this.exampleMethod.bind(this)).click();`
Nice and clean solution!

Comment: I still stick with the `bind()` function solution, but it's true that the way shown here does not allow to unbind the event later, as [pointed out by **kumkanillam**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48721038/7713952). So I wanted to document a [full example with both solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49170688/7713952).

Answer (score 1):

Each component has `click` handler and it will be called whenever component got clicked. But in your case, you want to trigger, component method whenever `body` element is clicked, so your approach is the way to go. but the only missing piece is `bind` and clearing the events.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  exampleProperty: 'example value',
  exampleMethodHandler: null,

   init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        //bind function will return the function with scope changed to this.
        this._exampleMethodHandler = Ember.run.bind(this, this.exampleMethod);
    },

  didInsertElement() {    
        this._super(...arguments);
        Ember.$('body').on('click', this._exampleMethodHandler);
  },
   willDestroyElement() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        //Need to clear the registered event handler.
        if (this._exampleMethodHandler) {
            Ember.$('body').off('click', this._exampleMethodHandler);
        }
    },
  exampleMethod() {
    //Here this will refers to component,
    console.log('ComponentProperty access as usual ",this.get('exampleProperty'),event); 
  },
});
```

Note: I cached the function reference returned by the bind function since we need to provide the exact same reference to tear down.

so

```
Ember.$('body').on('click',this.exampleMethod.bind(this))
Ember.$('body').off('click', this.exampleMethod);
```

The above will not tear down the attached event handler since both references are different.

Comment: Thank you, it works. To make it simpler, the `this` event parameter is not necessary, so on `didInsertElement()`: `Ember.$('body').click(this._exampleMethodHandler ).click();`, and remove `event` parameter on the method declaration: `exampleMethod()`. However I'll stick with Paul Bishop's solution as it's simpler. I'm using `willDestroyElement()` event but without the method handler, unbinding the method event directly: `Ember.$('body').off('click', this.exampleMethod);`

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer. I introduced caching for proper tear down, you can see in [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/53c90cdf19ef345625fb4b22c7a2b232?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) that Ember.$('body').off('click', this.exampleMethod); this will not tear down the event handler. Its trap we need to aware when we use bind function.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have a working solution, but I don't find it very elegant.

The Ember.js component must be passed to the callback function as event data:

**app/components/example-component.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  exampleProperty: 'example value',

  didInsertElement() {
    console.log('start didInsertElement() ************************************************************');
    console.log('- "this" is the Ember.js component:');
    console.log(this.$());
    console.log('- "this.exampleProperty" has the Ember.js component value:');
    console.log(this.exampleProperty);
    Ember.$('body').click(this, this.exampleMethod).click();
    console.log('end didInsertElement() ************************************************************');
  },
  exampleMethod(event) {
    console.log('start exampleMethod() ************************************************************');
    console.log('- "this" is the DOM element that has triggered the event:');
    console.log(Ember.$(this));
    // console.log(this.$()); This doesn't work
    console.log('- "this.exampleProperty" is undefined:');
    console.log(this.exampleProperty);
    console.log('- To access the component\'s "this.exampleProperty" the event data must be used:');
    const exampleComponent = event.data;
    console.log(exampleComponent.exampleProperty);
    console.log('end exampleMethod() ************************************************************');
  },
});
```

Here you have the [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/078cf211e0135a9069d4c6460ea6db4a?openFiles=components.example-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.example-component.hbs).

Although it is a working solution I find it ugly and unpractical. So if you have a better approach, please post.

There are other options that I find even worse, like passing the component property to the event data instead of the whole component, but this way if the property is updated the event data doesn't get the change.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide a full example with `bind()` following the [solution of Paul Bishop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48718108/7713952) but without the [unbounding problem pointed out by kumkanillam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48721038/7713952), and avoiding the use of an extra handler object like `exampleMethodHandler`:

**app/components/example-component.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  exampleProperty: 'example value',

  didInsertElement() {    
    this._super(...arguments);
    // create a new function with 'this' as bound argument
    this.exampleMethod = this.exampleMethod.bind(this);
    // bind exampleMethod() function to event without arguments
    Ember.$('body').click(this, this.exampleMethod).click();
  },
  willDestroyElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    // unbind exampleMethod() function from event successfully without arguments
    Ember.$('body').off('click', this.exampleMethod);
  },
  exampleMethod() {
    // inside exampleMethod() 'this' is the Ember.js component 
    // as bound before, not the DOM element that has triggered the event
    console.log('Ember.js property: ", this.get('exampleProperty')); 
  },
});
```

> The `bind()` function creates a new **bound function (BF)**. A **BF** is an
>   **exotic function object** (a term from **ECMAScript 2015**) that wraps the
>   original function object. Calling a **BF** generally results in the
>   execution of its **wrapped function**.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

So if using `bind()` creates a new function, it cannot be rerefenced later if  it's used anonymously. Hence, **this does not work:**

```
// bind() creates a new function which here is anonymous
Ember.$('body').click(this, this.exampleMethod.bind(this));
// this.exampleMethod() is not the former anonymous function
Ember.$('body').off('click', this.exampleMethod);
// here things are worse as a new anonymous function is created
Ember.$('body').off('click', this.exampleMethod.bind(this));
```

To be able to reference the new bound function later, it must be named:

```
// create new bound function and store it in 'this.exampleMethod'
this.exampleMethod = this.exampleMethod.bind(this);
// bound function this.exampleMethod() referenced
Ember.$('body').click(this, this.exampleMethod);
// same bound function this.exampleMethod() referenced again
Ember.$('body').off('click', this.exampleMethod);
```